# Using Signal R With VB.Net and Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, signalr

I've set up a Signal R client using MVC c# and with out front end i want to create a client side, being just a website connected to my aspx page. I've written the logic in javascript to be read by my page but can't find a way to open the connection to the Signal R server. I keep getting the error code Uncaught ReferenceError: signalR is not defined
at HTMLDocument. (NotificationPage.js:3:22)

this is my javascript,

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    // Connecting to the client>
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("https://localhost:57553/Chat/Index", {
            skipNegotiation: true,
            transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets})

    .build();
      
    // Recieving Messages
    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) => {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = `${user} said :  "${message}"`;
        document.getElementById("messageList").appendChild(li);
    });

    //Send Messages / clicking the button
    document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", async () => {
        const user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        const message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;


        try {
            await connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

    });

    async function start() {
        try {
            await connection.start();
            console.log("SignalR Connected.");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setTimeout(start, 5000);
        }
    };

    connection.onclose(async () => {
        await start();
    });

    // Start the connection.
    start();
});
```

when using it with RazorPages it opens with app.MapHub("/chat"); app.Run();

what is the equivalent of that to do in my back end using VB?

Comment: did you include the signalr javascript?

Comment: Yes in my aspx page i have this  <script src="NotificationPage.js"></script> which should link directly to the javascript

Comment: Not your script the one provided by signalr